# my 'if let' construction throws NSException in Swift. Why?

Tags: swift, swift3

In my `swift` app I have a block of code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "hashtagCell", for: indexPath) as! HashtagCollectionViewCell

    if let hashtagName:String =  self.suggestedHashtags[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item] as? String {
        cell.hashtagName.text = hashtagName
    } else {
        cell.hashtagName.text = "emptyHashtag"
    }

    cell.hashtagName.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
    cell.hashtagName.font = font

    return cell

}
```

and this line:

```
if let hashtagName:String =  self.suggestedHashtags[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item] as? String
```

sometimes crashes my app with the following error:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I thought that `if let` should handle this issue, but seems like it didn't. What might be the problem here?

Comment: This is unrelated to to your exception, but you can use `??` instead: `cell.hashtagName.text = (self.suggestedHashtags[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).item] as? String) ?? "emptyHashtag"`

Comment: and `IndexPath` has an `item` property.  There is no need to cast it to an `NSIndexPath`.

Comment: @vacawama I removed the casting and left only `indexPath.item` but again, it caused the error

Comment: Is your `suggestedHashTags` array big enough?  You could be crashing because your index is out of range.

Comment: @vacawama how can I handle it then if I do not know the size of an array?

Comment: @user3766930 you always know the size of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception is likely index out of range.  If your array might not be large enough to handle all items, you need to check.  Something like this would work:

```
cell.hashtagName.text = "emptyHashtag"
if indexPath.item < suggestedHashtags.count {
    if let hashtagName = suggestedHashtags[indexPath.item] as? String {
        cell.hashtagName.text = hashtagName
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree this is the issue, but it suggests a deeper problem that needs to be fixed. If `numberOfRows(inSection:)` returns `suggestedHashtags.count` (which it should), it should not be possible for this value to be out of range. So either `numberOfRows(inSection:)` is incorrect, or `suggestedHashtags` is being modified without correctly notifying the table.

Comment: ("not be possible" absent a bug in Cocoa. It is always *possible* that there is a bug in Cocoa, and most of us have run into many over the years, but it is far less likely than an error in your own code.)